# Finding average in pandas from a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

experimenting on a project with a large dataset of movies. I have a large data frame, with one row named "Genres" and one named "Vote Average". My goal is to find the 20 highest rated genres bases on "Vote Average".

I would use a group by but I can't seem to figure it out because the genre information looks like this in the column "Genres" :

```
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
```

How can I extract Comedy, Drama and Romance from the list above?
How can I group by individual genres while assigning the rows "Vote Average to each genre, so I can print the top 20 rated genres in the data frame?

```
     Genres  Vote Average
1      [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, '...           7.7
2      [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, '...           6.9
3      [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, ...           6.5
4      [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'nam...           6.1
5                         [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]           5.7
...                                                  ...           ...
32255           [{'id': 878, 'name': 'Science Fiction'}]           3.5
32256  [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name...           5.7
32257  [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 18, 'nam...           3.8
32258                                                 []           0.0
32259                                                 []           0.0
```

EDIT: Example from Data frame is above. movies_metadata.csv from https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset

Comment: Show what a portion of your dataframe looks like.

Comment: done! thank you for your help

Comment: That's a bad dataframe.  How did you make it? What was the data source? A csv file? A JSON?

Comment: dataframe should look like a table. Did you create this on your own?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, ...])` gives me correct table with columns `id` and `name`. You should first create correctly your file with data because it seems you screwed it up. You should go back to tocode which create current DataFrame and correct code to create it correctly. OR you have to iterate every row and convert to correct DataFrame using `pd.DataFrame([{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, ...])` and later join it to new global DataFrame.

Comment: data source was a csv file. Vote Average is above the column its supposed to be in PyCharm, also it has 24 columns I just cut it to 2 to make it easier.

Comment: if you created this CSV then you then you  screwed it up. Now You have to convert it to correct DataFrame with genres in separated rows insitead of `[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}`. And `PyCharm` has nothing to do with this. `PyCharm` is only tool to write code - more complex editor  - nothing more.

Comment: I did not create the csv, is is from Kaggle. MovieLens dataset

Comment: you could mention it in question. And you could add link to this page on Kaggle (also in question). It could explain some problems.

Comment: now when I see all information on kaggle then I think it may need totally different method because these genres are assigned to titles and they can't be in separated rows.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Now when I see all information on `kaggle` then I think it may need totally different method because these genres are assigned to titles and they can't be in separated rows.

---

**OLD:**

Now you have to convert it to correct `DataFrame` with genres in separated rows insitead of

```
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, ...]
```

Here is my example data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Genre': [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}], 'Vote Average': 7.7},
    {'Genre': [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}], 'Vote Average': 6.1},
    {'Genre': [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}], 'Vote Average': 6.5},
])

print(df)
```

result:

```
                                               Genre  Vote Average
0                  [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}]           7.7
1  [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'nam...           6.1
2                 [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]           6.5
```

You can iterate every row and use `pd.DataFrame(row['Genre'])` to create correct dataframe which you will add to new global dataframe

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name', 'Vote Average'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(row['Genre'])
    temp_df['Vote Average'] = row['Vote Average']
    new_df = new_df.append(temp_df)
    
print(new_df)
```

result:

```
      id       name  Vote Average
0     16  Animation           7.7
0     35     Comedy           6.1
1     18      Drama           6.1
2  10749    Romance           6.1
0  10749    Romance           6.5
```

and now you can do whatever you like.

---

Other method to correct data:

First convert list of dictionares to separated rows with dictionares

```
new_df = df.explode('Genre')
print(new_df)
```

result:

```
                          Genre  Vote Average
0   {'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}           7.7
1      {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}           6.1
1       {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}           6.1
1  {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}           6.1
2  {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}           6.5
```

and later convert every dictionary to columns

```
new_df['id'] = new_df['Genre'].str['id']
new_df['name'] = new_df['Genre'].str['name']
print(new_df)
```

result:

```
                              Genre  Vote Average     id       name
0   {'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}           7.7     16  Animation
1      {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}           6.1     35     Comedy
1       {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}           6.1     18      Drama
1  {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}           6.1  10749    Romance
2  {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}           6.5  10749    Romance
```

or using

```
new_df[['id','name']] = new_df['Genre'].apply(pd.Series)
```

---

Full example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Genre': [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}], 'Vote Average': 7.7},
    {'Genre': [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}], 'Vote Average': 6.1},
    {'Genre': [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}], 'Vote Average': 6.5},
])

print('--- df ---')
print(df)

print('--- iterrows ---')

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name', 'Vote Average'])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(row['Genre'])
    temp_df['Vote Average'] = row['Vote Average']
    new_df = new_df.append(temp_df)
    
print(new_df)    

print('--- explode #1 ---')
new_df = df.explode('Genre')
print(new_df)    

print('--- columns #1 ---')
new_df['id'] = new_df['Genre'].str['id']
new_df['name'] = new_df['Genre'].str['name']
new_df.drop('Genre', inplace=True, axis=1)
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(new_df)

print('--- explode #2 ---')
new_df = df.explode('Genre')
print(new_df)    

print('--- columns #2 ---')
new_df[['id','name']] = new_df['Genre'].apply(pd.Series)
new_df.drop('Genre', inplace=True, axis=1)
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: yes, often multiple genres are assigned to one title. I guess this is why first method did not work for me?

Comment: if you need only genres and votes then my answe can be some method for your problem but for something more it may need different method - it may need function which can check all `name` in dictionary and compare with some genre name and return `True/False` which can be used to filter rows with selected genre. And this function could be use with `df["Genres"].apply(...)`